# Backbone event adding extra events to radio button

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, radio-button

I have a set of radio buttons that I am testing with, will be used to change theme. Html code is straight forward

```
<div id="options">
    <input type="radio" name="imm" id="themea" value="a" /> Theme 1
    <input type="radio" name="imm" id="themeb"  value="b" /> Theme 2
</div>
```

How when I click on a radio item, the first time around the following code will show alert once, second time it will display twice, third time third and so on. What is going on, I reckon I need to destroy something but not sure what.

**Here is my backbone code:**

```
events: {
    "click input[type=radio]": "onRadioClick"
},
onRadioClick: function (e) {
    // e.stopPropagation();
    var self = this
    _.bindAll(self)

    $("input:radio[name=imm]").click(function (){
        var somval =  $(this).val();  
        alert(somval)
    });
```

**This is how I initialize the view:**

```
initialize: function(state) {
    var self = this
    _.bindAll(self)

    self.state = state
    self.setElement('#options')

    self.elem = {
        imm: self.$el.find('#imm')
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you bind click event one more time inside `onRadioClick`? This is your problem.

Comment: @dfsq You are 100% correct. Mark - Backbone is already giving you a click event, there is no need to also wire a jQuery click event. Plus you are not checking to see if it's already bound, and jQuery events are subscription based, so each time you are adding a new event to the 'click' chain of events, all on top of the orignial backbone event. Just remove the jQuery event and it should be fine.

Comment: #thanks for the answers. The reason why I was going through click again was that is was giving me the option clicked. Obviously this caused the looping then. When I write   alert( $("input:radio[name=imm]").val()) . I always just get the first option back, any ideas now to pull back the actual selected one. I reckon I'm missing something here, tried loads of combos of selected,value etc

Comment: @MarkOKeeffe Post a jsfiddle link with all the relevant code that duplicates the issue and I'll take a look.

Comment: @MarkOKeeffe By the way, did you try `$(e.target).val()` ?

Comment: By getting rid of the click event and adding in        alert(  $(e.target).val()) .I'm able to get the value. Thanks to all who helped, I can finally go to lunch